# Inconsistency on some Android mobile web browsers with tagging

Tags: android, jquery, mobile-website, mobile-browser, mention

I am using a jQuery plugin for allowing @mentions (tagging someone by inputing their name after an @ symbol).  The plug-in can be found here (http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/), and it has been working rather well.  The only issue (which may or may not have to do with the plug-in itself) that I've come across is that on certain Android devices, and particularly on certain mobile browsers, these @mentions will not work.  Interestingly, I discovered that if I turned Predictive Text off on these devices, it seemed to make the issue go away, but I am curious if there is a way to make it work without having to create a possibly poor user experience (i.e. forcing the user to turn predictive text off in order to tag).  The github repo for the plug in has addressed that there are some issues on Android, but it does not specify if that is referring to an Android App, or the web browsers for Android.  If anyone has come across a similar issue, I'd love to hear about possible solutions.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how the mentions don't work? Is it that the predictive text box doesn't appear? Clicking on the shown text box doesn't finish the tag? You see the default device predictive text instead of plugin's predictive text?

Comment: When inputing a tag, if you press the @ symbol and follow up with some letters, the usual flow is that after two letters, you should see a dropdown list of around 10 possible people to tag.  On these particular devices and while using particular browsers, WITH predictive text set to ON, you won't get that drop down menu at all.  The Predictive Text options appear just over the keyboard in a vertical list, not within the text-field itself.